# ASP.NET C# Cookie not keeping information after "Sign In Through Steam"

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Working with cookies is quite new to me. I am creating a website in ASP.NET using C# as the code behind. I have a sign in through steam button which works perfectly. However, when the user has clicked sign in through steam, I want the user to be redirected to the page that they were on when they clicked the button. I have tried to do this through the use of cookies.

ASPX

```
<li runat="server" id="login">
    <a onserverclick="LoginRedirect" runat="server">Sign In With Steam</a>
</li>
```

Navigation Bar in Master File C#

```
protected void LoginRedirect(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie PageBeforeAuthCookie = new HttpCookie("PageBeforeAuthCookie");
    PageBeforeAuth = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    PageBeforeAuthCookie.Value = PageBeforeAuth;
    Response.Cookies.Set(PageBeforeAuthCookie);
    Response.Cookies.Add(PageBeforeAuthCookie);
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
}
```

Login Page C#

```
if(Request.Cookies["PageBeforeAuthCookie"].Value != null)
{
    PageRedirUrl = Response.Cookies["PageBeforeAuthCookie"].Value;
}
else
{
    PageRedirUrl = "services.aspx";
}
Response.Redirect(PageRedirUrl);
```

After I have signed in through steam successfully, I am thrown an exception with these details: `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` for the line `Response.Redirect(PageRedirUrl);`

Comment: check you're setting the correct values to have the cookie persisted; also the signin with steam process should have a property to say where the user should be redirected after successful login

Comment: Is the cookie not being persisted with the code I provided? As this is the only code I have which interacts with this cookie. And yes, it does, but I need to use it like this to work with other functions that I have.

Comment: (very) generally speaking 3rd party logins have to work with a return url; you could redirect to a page that does further processing based on querystring or something and then redirect from there, but that's a smell to me; try and get your design working with a simple return url

Comment: That's the thing, it returns back to the login page after a successful sign in through steam, which then throws the exception, the redirect after sign in through steam is not the issue, it is basically just redirecting back to the page that they were on prior to clicking the button.